# How do i make python 3.6 import files relative to the file location?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple Python 3.6 program that I am writing with the following directory structure

```
src/
    Main.py
File_Readers/
    File_Reader.py
    Input_Reader.py
```

I wrote the Input_Reader.py file so that it had the following structure.

```
import File_Reader as fr

def read_finance_history(file_name, path_length)
    """
    Function in this section reads in a .csv and 
    places the data into a dictionary
    """
    return Dictionary

class FileReaderTest(unites.TestCase)
    def test_read_finance_history(self):
        """ Unit test code in this section """
```

I unit tested the  `Input_Reader.py` file in the `File_Readers` directory and it worked fine.  However, when i call the `Input_Reader.py` program via an import statement from the `Main.py` file, it does not recognize the `File_Reader` module called in the `Input_Reader.py` file.  Obviously the code is referencing everything from the `Main.py` location and I can fix the problem by changing the import statement in the `Input_Reader.py` file to read `from File_Readers import File_Reader as fr`, but then I can not run the unit tests from the `File_Readers` directory.  How can I force the import statements in the `Input_Reader.py` file to always import relative to the location of that file?

Answer (score 2):

Use `from . import File_Reader as fr`

Comment: This allows me to import when I call the file from `Main.py` in the `src` directory, but not if I run the unit test from directly from the `Input_Reader.py` file in the `File_Reader` directory.